# How do I use python sockets to send an api response over a connection?

Tags: python, sockets, server

I'm trying to have the server wait for a client to establish a connection, get data from the client, use that data to make an api request, and send the response to the client.  Everything works fine except for sending the response back to the client (client function just times out).  If put conn.sendall("anythinghere") inside of the while True loop, this works but obviously doesn't return what I need it to return.  Putting conn.sendall outside of the loop causes the timeout on the client side.

Server Code

```
conn, addr = s.accept()

print('Connected by', addr)
fragments = []
while True:
    chunk = conn.recv(4096)
    if not chunk:
        break
    fragments.append(chunk)

action = "".join(fragments)

URL = "http://172.31.55.211/" + action

print("making request")
r = requests.get(url = URL)
data = r.json()

conn.sendall(data['message'])
```

Client Code

```
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print(s)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'hellocvs')
    data = s.recv(1024)

    print('Received', repr(data))

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(str(data))
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your snippets are not executable. Please write a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your question

Comment: You server is looping until the client shuts down the write half of its connection, but that will never occur because the client is waiting to receive data from the server. Both are deadlocked. Instead, you need to define a protocol that enables the server to recognize when it has received the client's data.

Comment: Thank you @JamesKPolk .  That led me in the right direction and I got it working now.  Next time I'll try to post code that is more reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

At line `action = "".join(fragments)` server code will not run because `fragments` is `bytes not string` so you need `b''.join(fragments)` to join bytes